# Where do I change the "View Source" link shown in the Component Catalog in Backstage.io?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, backstage

I am able to successfully create a service in Backstage and create a new repository in GitLab. The Repository link is correctly linking me to my GitLab repository.

[image]

However, when I open the catalog and click on the View Source, the link it's directing me is wrong and incomplete.

[image]

For reference, if my repository link is gitlab.com/owner/repo-name, the view source link would redirect me to gitlab.com/owner/repo-name/-/blob/master when it should be gitlab.com/owner/repo-name/blob/master/catalog-info.yaml

Here is my template.yaml

```
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
# https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/descriptor-format#kind-template
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: template-name
  title: template name
  description: template decription
spec:
  owner: user:guest
  type: service

  # These parameters are used to generate the input form in the frontend, and are
  # used to gather input data for the execution of the template.
  parameters:
    - title: Fill in some steps
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          title: Name
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the component
          ui:autofocus: true
          ui:options:
            rows: 5
    - title: Choose a location
      required:
        - repoUrl
      properties:
        repoUrl:
          title: Repository Location
          type: string
          ui:field: RepoUrlPicker
          ui:options:
            allowedHosts:
              - gitlab.com

  # These steps are executed in the scaffolder backend, using data that we gathered
  # via the parameters above.
  steps:
    # Each step executes an action, in this case one templates files into the working directory.
    - id: fetch-base
      name: Fetch Base
      action: fetch:template
      input:
        url: ./skeleton
        values:
          name: ${{ parameters.name }}

    # This step publishes the contents of the working directory to GitHub.
    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:gitlab
      input:
        allowedHosts: [ 'gitlab.com' ]
        description: This is ${{ parameters.name }}
        repoUrl: ${{ parameters.repoUrl }}

    # The final step is to register our new component in the catalog.
    - id: register
      name: Register
      action: catalog:register
      input:
        repoContentsUrl: ${{ steps['publish'].output.repoContentsUrl }}
        catalogInfoPath: '/catalog-info.yaml'
          
  # Outputs are displayed to the user after a successful execution of the template.
  output:
    links:
      - title: Repository
        url: ${{ steps['publish'].output.remoteUrl }}
      - title: Open in catalog
        icon: catalog
        entityRef: ${{ steps['register'].output.entityRef }}
```

Where exactly do I configure it in my template.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the backstage.io/source-location annotations

```
annotations:
 backstage.io/source-location: url:https://gitlab.com
```